# Modify page scroll after url hash navigation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to account for navbar size after the page has loaded if a hash id has been passed in url e.g. `example.com#id-of-some-element`

I am trying to use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
        $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 80);
    }
});
```

However `$(window).scrollTop()` in this case always returns `0`.
This leads me to think that `.ready` fires before the navigation to the hash id has been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your theory is correct.  Below are 3 examples, one using `$(document).ready()`, one using `$(window).load()`, and one with logic to make the adjustment after the first scroll (but not subsequent scrolls).

All 3 show expected `$(window).scrollTop()` values, but `$(document).ready()` always appears in the hash location rather than the expected shifted location. `$(window).load()` appears with the expected 80px adjustment some of the time, but it is not consistent.  The third option uses logic that should always work, though it's admittedly a bit clunky.  There may be a better solution, but I hope this helps!

Try expanding each snippet and clicking "Run code snippet" repeatedly to see results over several test runs.

**Never works: Using `$(document).ready()`:**

```js
if (!window.location.hash) {
  window.location = window.location + "#id-of-some-element";
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 80);
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

```css
.tall-div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id-of-some-element">Some Element</div>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 2</div>
```

**Sometimes works: Using `$(window).load()`:**

```js
if (!window.location.hash) {
  window.location = window.location + "#id-of-some-element";
}

$(window).load(function() {
  console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 80);
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
  }
});
```

```css
.tall-div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id-of-some-element">Some Element</div>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 2</div>
```

**Always works: Using logic to detect first scroll:**

```js
if (!window.location.hash) {
  window.location = window.location + "#id-of-some-element";
}

var loading = true;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  if (loading) {
    console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    if (window.location.hash) {
      $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 80);
      console.log($(window).scrollTop());
    }
    loading = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.tall-div {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 1</div>
<div id="id-of-some-element">Some Element</div>
<div class="tall-div">DIV 2</div>
```